# Media manager for a Portable MP3 Player?

Tags: windows, file-synchronization, portable, media-manager

I'm looking for a media manager similar to Itunes>Ipod, that can sync folders to a portable MP3 player via selective Itunes playlists taken from the ItunesLibrary.xml file on Windows Music Folder.

I've bought a new portable MP3 player that has flash memory, and so it's similar to an ipod, although I can add folders of music to it similar to how it's done on an android. This player can also read txt ebooks, and display photographs, etc.

I'm looking for a way to manage the music on this media player via a windows software. Something similar to Itunes: Create playlists, and sync playlists. Although if possible, could it have an itunes import from the iTunesLibrary.xml too? Winamp can import the itunes library and playlists, so I was hoping if there are more softwares with the above requested features including the iTunes import?

That's mostly all.

Thanks!

EDIT: These two questions seemed similar, although both have different reconsiderations.

1. [ [Mediamonkey](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/571/music-manager-for-a-mass-storage-based-music-player) ] : Is there a portable version for this?
2. [ [Banshee](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/media-manager-similar-to-itunes-for-android) ] : Does Banshee sync with any portable player too? Or only Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find an app to directly import playlists from Itunes to a usb drive's folders, although found this music player called [Aimp](http://www.aimp.ru/).

[image: Aimp Music Player]

With this player I can transfer it's playlists to a portable mp3 player. Although it doesn't import playlists from Itunes.

Therefore, I created a utility on my own that now allows me to convert itunes playlists into normal .m3u playlists for import to AIMP.

Here's the Utility/Webapp that I've created for converting Itunes playlists into .m3u playlists.

[image: Itunes Playlist Converter]

Link: [iTunes-Library-Playlists-Converter](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27854284/Stuff/Music/iTunes-Library-Playlists-Converter/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [MusicBee](http://getmusicbee.com/). It's a great media manager/player application for windows with playlists and everything.

Although I've not checked its syncing abilities, I've copied songs and playlists to different devices and it works really well.